# tf cannot find boost thread library

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, thread, boost, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build ros hydro from source on ubuntu 12.04 it requires boost 1.46.1 but the version of boost installed on my machine is 1.48 so I downloaded boost 1.46.1 and installed it in a local folder. I also added skip-keys flag in rosdep to stop it from installing boost (because it would remove the newer version). After installing these dependencies I did  ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release as mentioned here : http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source

this started building plain cmake and catkin packages but gave an error while building tf:
CMakeFiles/tf_monitor.dir/src/tf_monitor.cpp.o: In function `main': tf_monitor.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3cf): undefined reference to` boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
tf_monitor.cpp:(.text.startup+0x46f): undefined reference to `boost::thread::join_noexcept()'

I specified the boost library path using CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH variable
cmake is able to find the local boost installation using this.
I also tried changing the CMakeCahe.txt file in tf package by specifying the location of libboost_thread.so but still no luck can someone please help .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199886/tf-cannot-find-boost-thread-library/) by [akhil](https://answers.ros.org/users/2787/akhil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2014-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally solved it by changing the boost_include and boost_library path in CMakeCache.txt file so that they point to the local boost installation

---

Originally posted by [akhil](https://answers.ros.org/users/2787/akhil/) with karma: 32 on 2014-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gustavo Henrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/29334/gustavo-henrique/) on 2017-09-01**:
Hi friend,

I have the same problem.

My question:

Link:  https://answers.ros.org/question/269944/instalation-ros-on-debian-wheezy-erro-boost/

You can help-me?

My robot is a P3AT with Debian Wheezy, 32 bits.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-01**:
If you have a new *question* please create a new one. http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do_Not